# How to create different background images for different views in ASP .NET Core web app

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core

I have a web application created in ASP .NET core. The designer created few pages with different background images. I implement my background images in  the Body tag that is in the _Layout shared view.
Is there someway to have multiple backgrounds or in other words different backgrounds for different views?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass in the path to the layout you want to use inside the view.

YourView.cshtml:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout_1.cshtml";
}
```

YourSecondView.cshtml:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout_2.cshtml";
}
```